# How can a non-native Korean speaker say "Pure Korean" or "Native Korean" in Korean?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

When talking about Korean word origin, there are "Pure/Native Korean" words, "Sino-Korean" (i.e. Hanja) words, and of course other origins like English. I am wondering how to say "Pure Korean" or "Native Korean" in Korean. I have heard "순한글" before talking about the numbers, but when I used it more generally, I was corrected and told to say "순우리말"; however, that obviously doesn't work well coming from a foreigner. I suggested "순한국말" or "순한국어" as alternatives, but supposedly that was awkward too. What should I call Pure/Native Korean words in Korean?

Comment: I was doing more research on this, and found that Naver Dictionary does in fact have [순 우리말 단어](http://endic.naver.com/krenIdiom.nhn?sLn=en&idiomId=873b2384ba7c49eb8c91dabf0fec426a&query=%EC%88%9C+%EC%9A%B0%EB%A6%AC%EB%A7%90+%EB%8B%A8%EC%96%B4). I also asked around to Koreans, and [고유어](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=en&isOnlyViewEE=N&query=%EA%B3%A0%EC%9C%A0%EC%96%B4) is another possible candidate.

Comment: I'd rather say and stick to “`고유어`.” That's how I was taught in school, a widely used term in the academic realm. The term referring to a native Korean word doesn't have to be one, amirite? =P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

순우리말:  I think this would be fine coming from a non-Korean. While being a Korean speaker or learner, you can consider it *yours*. Also the sense of 우리 in 순우리말 (without any spaces in it) has become attenuated.

순 한글:  This may be problematic because 한글 is supposed to mean the Korean script.  So a Sino-Korean word written in 한글 would be 순 한글. Text incorporating Chinese characters would be not 순 한글. Also I don't know that writing <strike>순한글</strike> (without spacing) is acceptable.

순 한국말, 순 한국어:  This too should serve your purpose.  Only, I don't know that writing these expressions without a space in them is acceptable.

As an aside, some people seem to question the idea of some words being more "pure" Korean than others.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I like that you said, "While being a Korean speaker or learner, you can consider it yours." I hadn't thought of it that way before.